# How to hide leaflet base map?

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping

I'm building a webGIS using leaflet library. Since the data visualization is for only a certain region, it seems that the broader leaflet base map looks a bit distracting. I wonder if there's a way to hide the redundant region.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, here are a few ideas:

1. Limit the map bounds and zoom to a certain range with [minZoom](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-minzoom), [maxZoom](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxzoom) and [maxBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds)
2. add an "inverted mask" to the area of interest. Check [Bjorn's mask plugin](http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/43c12f434d6bb47cd913), as well as the questions and answers [in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652189/dim-hide-rest-of-map-around-country-with-leaflet-js)

Comment: toms and @ghybs Thanks for your hints. I was able to sort it out.

Answer (score 4):

To go into more details, here are all your options (some may be combined):

1. Prevent Leaflet from loading tiles outside your area using the [`bounds` option of Tile Layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-bounds). That will save some network requests.
2. Restrict the map navigation to your area using [`maxBounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds) and [`minZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-minzoom) options of the Map object.
3. Hide the map outside your area using an inverted mask (a [polygon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon) with a hole being your area).
4. Alternatively with point 3, hide the map outside your area using [TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas plugin](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas). The advantage compared to point 3 is that there is no mask flickering on map navigation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276012/prevent-tiles-outside-of-polygon-from-loading

Comment: ghybs @toms Thanks for your hints. I was able to hide leaflet base map.